# How to get the value from the drop down box django? without submit button

Tags: django, django-templates

**How to get the value from the dropDown Box in Django Without Submit Button**

```
<div class="single-shorter">
    <form action="." method="GET">
        <label>Sort By :</label>
        <select name="val" id="val">                            
            <option selected="selected" value="name">Name</option>                                                  
            <option value="price">Price</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You use an AJAX request?

Comment: Without AJAX request possible?

Comment: If you want to get the value in backend Django Views then you have to pass it from making request. so you have to use AJAX for this. can you explain your use case?

Comment: i want make a product filter using dropdown if user click NAME (Product filter a name wise). if user click PRICE (Product filter a Price wise)

Comment: Can Explain how to use ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple obtain it using Ajax but as mentioned in comments in dont want to use that u can use value attribute in option value and using event listner and window.loction.href we can obtain this... This is one example

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="">Your Dropdown</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">x</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">y</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
```

as u are using django use this and also dont want to change the value attribute

```
<select id="my_selection">
<option value="x" href="/link/to/somewhere">value 1</option>
<option value="y" href="/link/to/somewhere/else">value 2</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');
}
</script>
```